# Distance between points on surface of cube

Tags: language-agnostic, geometry, cubes

Let `(x1, y1, z1)` and `(x2, y2, z2)` be two points in Euclidian 3-space on the surface of an axis-aligned side-length-2 **cube** centered at the origin.

How do I efficiently compute the distance (or squared distance) between the points **over the surface of the cube**?

Internally, I represent points as `(offset1, offset2, faceNumber)` but an `(x,y,z)` format (as referenced above) is readily available.

I prefer C or Python code but I'll happily accept pseudocode or anything, really.

EDIT:

Some facts:

1. Shortest paths are always monotone in x, y, and z.
2. If the points are on the same face then it's trivially just Euclidian distance.
3. If the points are not on the same face, the shortest path could involve either 2 or 3 faces.

Comment: What do you mean by "surface of the sphere?" What sphere?

Comment: @Kris, sorry, meant cube.

Comment: So you want the shortest path between the two points such that the path lies entirely on the surface of the cube?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Well, I want the length (or squared length) of that path, I don't actually need the path.

Comment: @KScottPiel, I wasn't able to find anything; if you have a good reference, I'd be delighted to see it.

Comment: z1 and z2 are face number? and not coordinate in the Z abscisse?

Comment: @MOHAMED, I edited for clarification. Pick your favorite representation. The offset-offset-face representation is good for seeing the relationship between the faces on which points reside; the x-y-z representation might be better for math.

Comment: there is parameter missing the side length of the cub

Comment: It says "axis-aligned **side-length-2** cube centered at the origin".

Comment: Your fact 3 is not always true: there are pairs of points where the shortest route involves 4 faces.  http://www.se16.info/js/cube31.gif illustrates a particular case where there are four shortest routes using 3, 3, 3, and 4 faces between the points (0.8, 0.6, 1) and (-0.8, -0.4, -1).  With a cuboid, [the shortest route can involve 5 faces](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpiderandFlyProblem.html)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: What I would do, is turn the 3d cube into a 2d plane.  The caveat is that, if the point is on the opposite side of the cube, you need to place the final surface on all ends of the cross.

If a cube had sides like this that you could fold around so that 4 touched side 1.

```
5
1 2 3 4 
6
```

You would have a 2d plane that ultimately looked like this

```
         3
    4/5  5   5/2
3   4    1   2   3
    4/6  6   2/6
         3
```

So, I modified this.  Now each of the corner panels represents the connections that can take place between both panels.  When you initially lay out this array, each point on panels 2, 4, 5, and 6, will map to three points.  The solution is then the shortest line to any of the given points, that represent point 2, in the event you need to map it to multiple points.

Mapping points from the 3d cube, to their initial 1 - 6 pains on the 2d graph is really quite simple.  The only difficulty left is figuring out how to map points from the 2 plane, onto the "2/6" plane and so forth.  This is just a matter of thinking through each situation.  Ex: 2 -> 2/6 is different from 5 -> 5/2.  My intuition is that it's either going to be 90 degree or -90 degree rotation, before shifting the width of the cube in the appropriate direction.

For example, to properly handle the situation you laid out we would have a value at the bottom left corner of plane one, and the bottom right corner of plane 2.  After the following: '

```
points in plane 2/6 = rot90(points in plane 2) - width of the cube.
```

We will have a point in the bottom left corner of plane 2/6.  This will then appropriately be the shortest path, and appropriately this path crosses the face of plane 6.

Comment: Hi @ChrisCM, is this in Euclidian 3-space or over the surface of the cube? I want the latter.

Comment: This is not a bad way to do it.

Comment: @ChrisCM, suppose they're on adjacent faces. The problem is easy (I think) if they're on the same or opposite faces. How do you unfold? If the points are on sides 2 and 6 then the path could go from 2 to 6, or from 2 to 1 to 6 or from 2 to 3 to 6, depending on the geometry.

Comment: This solution assumes that you have normalized it so that at least one of the points exists on "side 1" I actually anticipated this comment and have already edited the solution.

Comment: @ChrisCM, the shortest path could still go from 1 to 2 to 6, for example.

Comment: No, because there would always be a shorter path that would just go from 1 to 6.

Comment: I think this *might* be feasible if you normalize so that the two faces are 1 and 2, and then hard-code the 3rd-face logic, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ChrisCM: consider these points: `(1, .99, .99)` and `(-.99, .99, 1)`. If you go direct then you get a distance of about 4, if you go over a 3rd face you get a distance of about `sqrt(2^2 + 2^2)`.

Comment: Without reference for how big your cube is this doesn't mean much to me.  Consider this: Does the diagram I put forth easily represent a cube? yes, of course.  Now draw a straight line from a point on the first side to any point not on the third side.  Does this straight line ever cross a third face?

Comment: ChrisCM: look at this: http://i.imgur.com/J1aERBm.png -- the shortest path *must* cross the front even though the points are on the top and right.

Comment: Ah I see, hard to visualize without reference for how big your cube was, now I see your point.  I will consider this over lunch.  Similar logic is still usable though.

Comment: I modified the solution for your example.  For the example you gave, I believe you would see a value in the top right corner of panel 1, and top left corner of panel 4.  This would then be correctly mirrored to the top right corner of panel 4/5, as an additional point.  Then it is simple math to compute the diagonal route to 4/5 as the shortest route.  The mapping to the sub panels is going to be tricky, but not too difficult.  Just don't forget the mirroring/rotation that needs to take place.

Comment: I believe that this technique could work; thanks. However, the answer obscures the details; I'm not going to accept an answer unless it discusses implementation specifics.

Comment: The implementation details in this case are very simple.  Anyone who knows math even a little can shift values around a graph, rotate values 90 degrees, or normalize a graph to a new origin.  That being said, it's still a lot of code.  I provided a few more details to remove some of the ambiguity, but really, the full solution is there.  It just needs put to code.